# iphone 4s unable to play tone alerts

Tags: iphone

For some reason, the sounds for ringers, and alerts/notifications on my iPhone appear to not be playing anymore. Even though the ringer volume in settings is turned up almost to the max, the phone still only vibrates when receiving a call. And when the phone is placed onto it's charging dock, instead of BEEP ing like it normally does, it simply vibrates.

Interestingly, when I fiddle with the ringer volume slider in settings, the test ringtone plays just fine, and music audio cannot be played through the built in speaker.

What's going on?
please suggest some solution.

Comment: Do you have the Silent switch turned on (on the left side towards the top). If its turned on (pushed towards the back of the phone), everything you describe would be occurring.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the Silent switch is turned on. Check on the left side of the iphone and make sure that the silent switch does not show red.

If it is not in silent mode, change try changing the ringtone and see if it works. If not reset the iphone from settings->general->reset->reset all settings.

If both methods does not work contact an Apple Genius.

Comment: i did try the reset thing. but still the problem is not solved yet..

Comment: I know how frustrated you are, because this happened to me once. But I managed ta fix it by changing the volume and changing the ringtone. If you still cannot resolve this issue try contacting Apple support.